# How to find min & max average of numbers , sorting names

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
    char Firstname[20];
    char Lastname[20];
    int sn;
    float avg;
public:
    void input()
    {
        cin >> this->Firstname >> this->Lastname >> this->sn;
    }

    int cal_sum()
    {
        float a, b, c, d, e, sum, avg;
        cout << "enter the scores : " << endl;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
        sum = a + b + c + d + e;
        avg = sum / 5;
        cout << "avg = " << avg << endl;
        if (a <= b && a <= c && a <= d && a <= e)
            cout << "min = " << a << endl;
        if (b <= a && b <= c && b <= d && b <= e)
            cout << "min = " << b << endl;
        if (c <= a && c <= b && c <= d && c <= e)
            cout << "min = " << c << endl;
        if (d <= a && d <= b && d <= c && d <= e)
            cout << "min = " << d << endl;
        if (e <= a && e <= b && e <= c && e <= d)
            cout << "min = " << e << endl;
        if (a >= b && a >= c && a >= d && a >= e)
            cout << "max = " << a << endl;
        if (b >= a && b >= c && b >= d && b >= e)
            cout << "max = " << b << endl;
        if (c >= a && c >= b && c >= d && c >= e)
            cout << "max = " << c << endl;
        if (d >= a && d >= b && d >= c && d >= e)
            cout << "max = " << d << endl;
        if (e >= a && e >= b && e >= c && e >= d)
            cout << "max = " << e << endl;
        return (0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    student A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J;
    A.input();
    A.cal_sum();
    B.input();
    B.cal_sum();
    C.input();
    C.cal_sum();
    D.input();
    D.cal_sum();
    E.input();
    E.cal_sum();
    F.input();
    F.cal_sum();
    G.input();
    G.cal_sum();
    H.input();
    H.cal_sum();
    I.input();
    I.cal_sum();
    J.input();
    J.cal_sum();
}
```

I want the following conditions to be observed in this program:

1. receive information of 10 students(name, student number, at least 5 scores)
2. input & print information of students by 2 different functions
3. calculate average scores of each students
4. find min & max of each student scores
5. find min & max average score among all students
6. sorting names of students
7. receive a specific student name or student number from the entry and search it among students

I tried many ways for the last three conditions, but I don't know how to set them.

Comment: Arrays or (even better) `std::vector` was not yet taught in your course?

Comment: @OP What if you had 100 or a thousand numbers to take the average of?  Would you create a 100 or thousand variables?  Why did you use arrays here `char Firstname[20];`, and not have an array of `float`?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat -- Arrays were or seemed to be have been taught:  `char Firstname[20];`.  I guess the OP didn't know the purpose of arrays.

Comment: `student A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J;` --> `student aStudent[10];` -- You can start there, instead of declaring 10 separate `student` variables.  Again, you are already using arrays of `char`, so there is no excuse not to use arrays here (and in other places).

Comment: [Teaser on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4941d11e67c486d1) ;-)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i need 5 numbers for average

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: @sinakh -- *i need 5 numbers for average* -- `float values[5];` -- That is the point that I'm attempting to make.  There is no need for 5 separate variables.  Then taking the average and finding the min and max are done with a simple loop, not an endless set of `if` statements.

Comment: Try using loops or functions defined in C++ to do the min and max comparison for any number of inputs. Avoid such hard coding.
Also take a look at @AlanBirtles comment link.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you show and explain the exact code of the program? ((float values[5];)) and ((student aStudent[10];))